# Update a ListView from different threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

Sorry if the question seems silly.. I'm still learning Java. I just wanted to know, is it possible to update my ListView in `MainActivity` class from different threads? I tried passing my activity context in thread constructor and get instance of `ListView` like this:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.listViewInXml);
```

Then I updated this `ListView` as per my requirement after the thread execution is complete. But the problem is, each thread gets different instance on the `ListView` and each one of them adds item to the 0 index (it assumes the `ListView` is newly created at the start of each thread). I want that each thread completes its execution and add the result on by one in the `ListView` of `MainActivity` class. Any suggestions please? Here is a skeleton of what I'm trying to do:

```
    MainActivity extends Activity {

onCreate (bundle icicle) {

   getReferencetoListView();
   int userId = 1;
   while (true) {  
      // Execute a thread with userId
     // Each thread takes some time to complete execution
     userId++
     }
  }
}

Thread (userId =1)

Thread (userId =2)

Thread (userId =3) 
.
.
.
and so on..
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: More easy is to create a `Handler` associated with UI thread and manipulate `ListView` from this handler. In handler's `handleMessage()` code, you can manage order of adding/modifying items so threads won't care about it, just do their work and send messages when work is done.

Comment: I think you can do something like this. update your adapter in thread when thread finishes you can update list by calling notifydatasetchanged

Comment: So, I should get reference to my ListView in MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to know, is it possible to update my ListView in MainActivity class from different threads?

No. You cannot modify the UI from a background thread outside of a few select cases (e.g., `ProgressBar`). This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

Comment: @Salauyou: `runOnUiThread()` takes a `Runnable` and runs it on the main application ("UI") thread. If that `Runnable` updates the `ListView`, then it is not updating the `ListView` on a background thread. A background thread can *prepare* data for a `ListView`, but then the actual *update* of the `ListView` itself has to happen on the main application therad.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt here. I tested the program by updating the ListView in runOnUiThread(). But this doesn't solve my problem. It still updates it's own instance of ListView (which is instantiated everytime the thread is launched). So all items are added to zero index!

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks ) I understand the mechanism how it works, the question was not about updating UI _on_ background thread, but _from_ it. For me, there is a difference.

Comment: @VinitShandilya: Either you are creating your own multiple instances of the `ListView` or you are misinterpreting your tests. `findViewById()` does not create widgets -- it returns widgets that were created by something else (e.g., `setContentView()`).